# How to block SEMRUSH bots in IIS

Tags: iis, bots

We are receiving tons of web request from SEMRUSH bots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGjtf.jpg
How to block them in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use IP address and domain restrictions feature of IIS.

[image]

```
 <security>
  <!-- To block IP addresses, see example format below. Add to list as needed: -->
  <ipSecurity>
    <add ipAddress="ip" allowed="false" />
  </ipSecurity>
```

and you could use request blocking rule using iis url rewrite.below is a rule:

```
  <rule name="Abuse User Agents Blocking" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*(1Noonbot|1on1searchBot|3D_SEARCH|3DE_SEARCH2|3GSE|50.nu|192.comAgent|360Spider|A6-Indexer|AASP|ABACHOBot|Abonti|abot|AbotEmailSearch|Aboundex|AboutUsBot|AccMonitor\ Compliance|accoona|AChulkov.NET\ page\ walker|Acme.Spider|AcoonBot|acquia-crawler|ActiveTouristBot|Acunetix|Ad\ Muncher|AdamM|adbeat_bot|adminshop.com|Advanced\ Email|AESOP_com_SpiderMan|AESpider|AF\ Knowledge\ Now\ Verity|aggregator:Vocus|ah-ha.com|AhrefsBot|AIBOT|aiHitBot|aipbot|AISIID|AITCSRobot|Akamai-SiteSnapshot|AlexaWebSearchPlatform|AlexfDownload|Alexibot|AlkalineBOT|All\ Acronyms|Amfibibot|AmPmPPC.com|AMZNKAssocBot|Anemone|Anonymous|Anonymouse.org|AnotherBot|AnswerBot|AnswerBus|AnswerChase\ PROve|AntBot|antibot-|AntiSantyWorm|Antro.Net|AONDE-Spider|Aport|Aqua_Products|AraBot|Arachmo|Arachnophilia|archive.org_bot|aria\ eQualizer|arianna.libero.it|Arikus_Spider|Art-Online.com|ArtavisBot|Artera|ASpider|ASPSeek|asterias|AstroFind|athenusbot|AtlocalBot|Atomic_Email_Hunter|attach|attrakt|attributor|Attributor.comBot|augurfind|AURESYS|AutoBaron|autoemailspider|autowebdir|AVSearch-|axfeedsbot|Axonize-bot|Ayna|b2w|BackDoorBot|BackRub|BackStreet\ Browser|BackWeb|Baiduspider-video|Bandit|BatchFTP|baypup|BDFetch|BecomeBot|BecomeJPBot|BeetleBot|Bender|besserscheitern-crawl|betaBot|Big\ Brother|Big\ Data|Bigado.com|BigCliqueBot|Bigfoot|BIGLOTRON|Bilbo|BilgiBetaBot|BilgiBot|binlar|bintellibot|bitlybot|BitvoUserAgent|Bizbot003|BizBot04|BizBot04\ kirk.overleaf.com|Black.Hole|Black\ Hole|Blackbird|BlackWidow|bladder\ fusion|Blaiz-Bee|BLEXBot|Blinkx|BlitzBOT|Blog\ Conversation\ Project|BlogMyWay|BlogPulseLive|BlogRefsBot|BlogScope|Blogslive|BloobyBot|BlowFish|BLT|bnf.fr_bot|BoaConstrictor|BoardReader-Image-Fetcher|BOI_crawl_00|BOIA-Scan-Agent|BOIA.ORG-Scan-Agent|boitho.com-dc|Bookmark\ Buddy|bosug|Bot\ Apoena|BotALot|BotRightHere|Botswana|bottybot|BpBot|BRAINTIME_SEARCH|BrokenLinkCheck.com|BrowserEmulator|BrowserMob|BruinBot|BSearchR&amp;D|BSpider|btbot|Btsearch|Buddy|Buibui|BuildCMS|BuiltBotTough|Bullseye|bumblebee|BunnySlippers|BuscadorClarin|Butterfly|BuyHawaiiBot|BuzzBot|byindia|BySpider|byteserver|bzBot|c\ r\ a\ w\ l\ 3\ r|CacheBlaster|CACTVS\ Chemistry|Caddbot|Cafi|Camcrawler|CamelStampede|Canon-WebRecord|Canon-WebRecordPro|CareerBot|casper|cataguru|CatchBot|CazoodleBot|CCBot|CCGCrawl|ccubee|CD-Preload|CE-Preload|Cegbfeieh|Cerberian\ Drtrs|CERT\ FigleafBot|cfetch|CFNetwork|Chameleon|ChangeDetection|Charlotte|Check&amp;Get|Checkbot|Checklinks|checkprivacy|CheeseBot|ChemieDE-NodeBot|CherryPicker|CherryPickerElite|CherryPickerSE|Chilkat|ChinaClaw|CipinetBot|cis455crawler|citeseerxbot|cizilla.com|ClariaBot|clshttp|Clushbot|cmsworldmap|coccoc|CollapsarWEB|Collector|combine|comodo|conceptbot|ConnectSearch|conpilot|ContentSmartz|ContextAd|contype|cookieNET|CoolBott|CoolCheck|Copernic|Copier|CopyRightCheck|core-project|cosmos|Covario-IDS|Cowbot-|Cowdog|crabbyBot|crawl|Crawl_Application|crawl.UserAgent|CrawlConvera|crawler|crawler_for_infomine|CRAWLER-ALTSE.VUNET.ORG-Lynx|crawler-upgrade-config|crawler.kpricorn.org|crawler@|crawler4j|crawler43.ejupiter.com|Crawly|CreativeCommons|Crescent|Crescent\ Internet\ ToolPak\ HTTP\ OLE\ Control|cs-crawler|CSE\ HTML\ Validator|CSHttpClient|Cuasarbot|culsearch|Curl|Custo|Cutbot|cvaulev|Cyberdog|CyberNavi_WebGet|CyberSpyder|CydralSpider).*$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*(D1GArabicEngine|DA|DataCha0s|DataFountains|DataparkSearch|DataSpearSpiderBot|DataSpider|Dattatec.com|Dattatec.com-Sitios-Top|Daumoa|DAUMOA-video|DAUMOA-web|Declumbot|Deepindex|deepnet|DeepTrawl|dejan|del.icio.us-thumbnails|DelvuBot|Deweb|DiaGem|Diamond|DiamondBot|diavol|DiBot|didaxusbot|DigExt|Digger|DiGi-RSSBot|DigitalArchivesBot|DigOut4U|DIIbot|Dillo|Dir_Snatch.exe|DISCo|DISCo\ Pump|discobot|DISCoFinder|Distilled-Reputation-Monitor|Dit|DittoSpyder|DjangoTraineeBot|DKIMRepBot|DoCoMo|DOF-Verify|domaincrawler|DomainScan|DomainWatcher|dotbot|DotSpotsBot|Dow\ Jonesbot|Download|Download\ Demon|Downloader|DOY|dragonfly|Drip|drone|DTAAgent|dtSearchSpider|dumbot|Dwaar|Dwaarbot|DXSeeker|EAH|EasouSpider|EasyDL|ebingbong|EC2LinkFinder|eCairn-Grabber|eCatch|eChooseBot|ecxi|EdisterBot|EduGovSearch|egothor|eidetica.com|EirGrabber|ElisaBot|EllerdaleBot|EMail\ Exractor|EmailCollector|EmailLeach|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|EMPAS_ROBOT|EnaBot|endeca|EnigmaBot|Enswer\ Neuro|EntityCubeBot|EroCrawler|eStyleSearch|eSyndiCat|Eurosoft-Bot|Evaal|Eventware|Everest-Vulcan|Exabot|Exabot-Images|Exabot-Test|Exabot-XXX|ExaBotTest|ExactSearch|exactseek.com|exooba|Exploder|explorersearch|extract|Extractor|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE|ez-robot|Ezooms|factbot|FairAd\ Client|falcon|Falconsbot|fast-search-engine|FAST\ Data\ Document|FAST\ ESP|fastbot|fastbot.de|FatBot|Favcollector|Faviconizer|FDM|FedContractorBot|feedfinder|FelixIDE|fembot|fetch_ici|Fetch\ API\ Request|fgcrawler|FHscan|fido|Filangy|FileHound|FindAnISP.com_ISP_Finder|findlinks|FindWeb|Firebat|Fish-Search-Robot|Flaming\ AttackBot|Flamingo_SearchEngine|FlashCapture|FlashGet|flicky|FlickySearchBot|flunky|focused_crawler|FollowSite|Foobot|Fooooo_Web_Video_Crawl|Fopper|FormulaFinderBot|Forschungsportal|fr_crawler|Francis|Freecrawl|FreshDownload|freshlinks.exe|FriendFeedBot|frodo.at|froGgle|FrontPage|Froola|FU-NBI|full_breadth_crawler|FunnelBack|FunWebProducts|FurlBot|g00g1e|G10-Bot|Gaisbot|GalaxyBot|gazz|gcreep|generate_infomine_category_classifiers|genevabot|genieBot|GenieBotRD_SmallCrawl|Genieo|Geomaxenginebot|geometabot|GeonaBot|GeoVisu|GermCrawler|GetHTMLContents|Getleft|GetRight|GetSmart|GetURL.rexx|GetWeb!|Giant|GigablastOpenSource|Gigabot|Girafabot|GleameBot|gnome-vfs|Go-Ahead-Got-It|Go!Zilla|GoForIt.com|GOFORITBOT|gold|Golem|GoodJelly|Gordon-College-Google-Mini|goroam|GoSeebot|gotit|Govbot|GPU\ p2p|grab|Grabber|GrabNet|Grafula|grapeFX|grapeshot|GrapeshotCrawler|grbot|GreenYogi\ [ZSEBOT]|Gromit|GroupMe|grub|grub-client|Grubclient-|GrubNG|GruBot|gsa|GSLFbot|GT::WWW|Gulliver|GulperBot|GurujiBot|GVC|GVC\ BUSINESS|gvcbot.com|HappyFunBot|harvest|HarvestMan|Hatena\ Antenna|Hawler|Hazel's\ Ferret\ hopper|hcat|hclsreport-crawler|HD\ nutch\ agent|Header_Test_Client|healia|Helix|heritrix|hijbul-heritrix-crawler|HiScan|HiSoftware\ AccMonitor|HiSoftware\ AccVerify|hitcrawler_|hivaBot|hloader|HMSEbot|HMView|hoge|holmes|HomePageSearch|Hooblybot-Image|HooWWWer|Hostcrawler|HSFT\ -\ Link|HSFT\ -\ LVU|HSlide|ht:|htdig|Html\ Link\ Validator|HTMLParser|HTTP::Lite|httplib|HTTrack|Huaweisymantecspider|hul-wax|humanlinks|HyperEstraier|Hyperix).*$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*(ia_archiver|IAArchiver-|ibuena|iCab|ICDS-Ingestion|ichiro|iCopyright\ Conductor|id-search|IDBot|IEAutoDiscovery|IECheck|iHWebChecker|IIITBOT|iim_405|IlseBot|IlTrovatore|Iltrovatore-Setaccio|ImageBot|imagefortress|ImagesHereImagesThereImagesEverywhere|ImageVisu|imds_monitor|imo-google-robot-intelink|IncyWincy|Industry\ Cortexcrawler|Indy\ Library|indylabs_marius|InelaBot|Inet32\ Ctrl|inetbot|InfoLink|INFOMINE|infomine.ucr.edu|InfoNaviRobot|Informant|Infoseek|InfoTekies|InfoUSABot|INGRID|Inktomi|InsightsCollector|InsightsWorksBot|InspireBot|InsumaScout|Intelix|InterGET|Internet\ Ninja|InternetLinkAgent|Interseek|IOI|ip-web-crawler.com|Ipselonbot|Iria|IRLbot|Iron33|Isara|iSearch|iSiloX|IsraeliSearch|IstellaBot|its-learning|IU_CSCI_B659_class_crawler|iVia|iVia\ Page\ Fetcher|JadynAve|JadynAveBot|jakarta|Jakarta\ Commons-HttpClient|Java|Jbot|JemmaTheTourist|JennyBot|Jetbot|JetBrains\ Omea\ Pro|JetCar|Jim|JoBo|JobSpider_BA|JOC|JoeDog|JoyScapeBot|JSpyda|JubiiRobot|jumpstation|Junut|JustView|Jyxobot|K.S.Bot|KakcleBot|kalooga|KaloogaBot|kanagawa|KATATUDO-Spider|Katipo|kbeta1|Kenjin.Spider|KeywenBot|Keyword.Density|Keyword\ Density|kinjabot|KIT-Fireball|Kitenga-crawler-bot|KiwiStatus|kmbot-|kmccrew|Knight|KnowItAll|Knowledge.com|Knowledge\ Engine|KoepaBot|Koninklijke|KrOWLer|KSbot|kuloko-bot|kulturarw3|KummHttp|Kurzor|Kyluka|L.webis|LabelGrab|Labhoo|labourunions411|lachesis|Lament|LamerExterminator|LapozzBot|larbin|LARBIN-EXPERIMENTAL|LBot|LeapTag|LeechFTP|LeechGet|LetsCrawl.com|LexiBot|LexxeBot|lftp|libcrawl|libiViaCore|libWeb|libwww|libwww-perl|likse|Linguee|Link|link_checker|LinkAlarm|linkbot|LinkCheck\ by\ Siteimprove.com|LinkChecker|linkdex.com|LinkextractorPro|LinkLint|linklooker|Linkman|LinkScan|LinksCrawler|LinksManager.com_bot|LinkSweeper|linkwalker|LiteFinder|LitlrBot|Little\ Grabber\ at\ Skanktale.com|Livelapbot|LM\ Harvester|LMQueueBot|LNSpiderguy|LoadTimeBot|LocalcomBot|locust|LolongBot|LookBot|Lsearch|lssbot|LWP|lwp-request|lwp-trivial|LWP::Simple|Lycos_Spider|Lydia\ Entity|LynnBot|Lytranslate|Mag-Net|Magnet|magpie-crawler|Magus|Mail.Ru|Mail.Ru_Bot|MAINSEEK_BOT|Mammoth|MarkWatch|MaSagool|masidani_bot_|Mass|Mata.Hari|Mata\ Hari|matentzn\ at\ cs\ dot\ man\ dot\ ac\ dot\ uk|maxamine.com--robot|maxamine.com-robot|maxomobot|Maxthon$|McBot|MediaFox|medrabbit|Megite|MemacBot|Memo|MendeleyBot|Mercator-|mercuryboard_user_agent_sql_injection.nasl|MerzScope|metacarta|Metager2|metager2-verification-bot|MetaGloss|METAGOPHER|metal|metaquerier.cs.uiuc.edu|METASpider|Metaspinner|MetaURI|MetaURI\ API|MFC_Tear_Sample|MFcrawler|MFHttpScan|Microsoft.URL|MIIxpc|miner|mini-robot|minibot|miniRank|Mirror|Missigua\ Locator|Mister.PiX|Mister\ PiX|Miva|MJ12bot|mnoGoSearch|mod_accessibility|moduna.com|moget|MojeekBot|MOMspider|MonkeyCrawl|MOSES|Motor|mowserbot|MQbot|MSE360|MSFrontPage|MSIECrawler|MSIndianWebcrawl|MSMOBOT|Msnbot|msnbot-products|MSNPTC|MSRBOT|MT-Soft|MultiText|My_Little_SearchEngine_Project|my-heritrix-crawler|MyApp|MYCOMPANYBOT|mycrawler|MyEngines-US-Bot|MyFamilyBot|Myra|nabot|nabot_|Najdi.si|Nambu|NAMEPROTECT|NatchCVS|naver|naverbookmarkcrawler|NaverBot|Navroad|NearSite|NEC-MeshExplorer|NeoScioCrawler|NerdByNature.Bot|NerdyBot|Nerima-crawl-).*$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*(T-H-U-N-D-E-R-S-T-O-N-E|Tailrank|tAkeOut|TAMU_CRAWLER|TapuzBot|Tarantula|targetblaster.com|TargetYourNews.com|TAUSDataBot|taxinomiabot|Tecomi|TeezirBot|Teleport|Teleport\ Pro|TeleportPro|Telesoft|Teradex\ Mapper|TERAGRAM_CRAWLER|TerrawizBot|testbot|testing\ of|TextBot|thatrobotsite.com|The.Intraformant|The\ Dyslexalizer|The\ Intraformant|TheNomad|Theophrastus|theusefulbot|TheUsefulbot_|ThumbBot|thumbshots-de-bot|tigerbot|TightTwatBot|TinEye|Titan|to-dress_ru_bot_|to-night-Bot|toCrawl|Topicalizer|topicblogs|Toplistbot|TopServer\ PHP|topyx-crawler|Touche|TourlentaScanner|TPSystem|TRAAZI|TranSGeniKBot|travel-search|TravelBot|TravelLazerBot|Treezy|TREX|TridentSpider|Trovator|True_Robot|tScholarsBot|TsWebBot|TulipChain|turingos|turnit|TurnitinBot|TutorGigBot|TweetedTimes|TweetmemeBot|TwengaBot|TwengaBot-Discover|Twiceler|Twikle|twinuffbot|Twisted\ PageGetter|Twitturls|Twitturly|TygoBot|TygoProwler|Typhoeus|U.S.\ Government\ Printing\ Office|uberbot|ucb-nutch|UCSD-Crawler|UdmSearch|UFAM-crawler-|Ultraseek|UnChaos|unchaos_crawler_|UnisterBot|UniversalSearch|UnwindFetchor|UofTDB_experiment|updated|URI::Fetch|url_gather|URL-Checker|URL\ Control|URLAppendBot|URLBlaze|urlchecker|urlck|UrlDispatcher|urllib|URLSpiderPro|URLy.Warning|USAF\ AFKN\|usasearch|USS-Cosmix|USyd-NLP-Spider|Vacobot|Vacuum|VadixBot|Vagabondo|Validator|Valkyrie|vBSEO|VCI|VerbstarBot|VeriCiteCrawler|Verifactrola|Verity-URL-Gateway|vermut|versus|versus.integis.ch|viasarchivinginformation.html|vikspider|VIP|VIPr|virus-detector|VisBot|Vishal\ For\ CLIA|VisWeb|vlad|vlsearch|VMBot|VocusBot|VoidEYE|VoilaBot|Vortex|voyager|voyager-hc|voyager-partner-deep|VSE|vspider).*$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*(W3C_Unicorn|W3C-WebCon|w3m|w3search|wacbot|wastrix|Water\ Conserve|Water\ Conserve\ Portal|WatzBot|wauuu\ engine|Wavefire|Waypath|Wazzup|Wazzup1.0.4800|wbdbot|web-agent|Web-Sniffer|Web.Image.Collector|Web\ CEO\ Online|Web\ Image\ Collector|Web\ Link\ Validator|Web\ Magnet|webalta|WebaltBot|WebAuto|webbandit|webbot|webbul-bot|WebCapture|webcheck|Webclipping.com|webcollage|WebCopier|WebCopy|WebCorp|webcrawl.net|webcrawler|WebDownloader\ for|Webdup|WebEMailExtrac|WebEMailExtrac.*|WebEnhancer|WebFerret|webfetch|WebFetcher|WebGather|WebGo\ IS|webGobbler|WebImages|Webinator-search2.fasthealth.com|Webinator-WBI|WebIndex|WebIndexer|weblayers|WebLeacher|WeblexBot|WebLinker|webLyzard|WebmasterCoffee|WebmasterWorld|WebmasterWorldForumBot|WebMiner|WebMoose|WeBot|WebPix|WebReaper|WebRipper|WebSauger|Webscan|websearchbench|WebSite|websitemirror|WebSpear|websphinx.test|WebSpider|Webster|Webster.Pro|Webster\ Pro|WebStripper|WebTrafficExpress|WebTrends\ Link\ Analyzer|webvac|webwalk|WebWalker|Webwasher|WebWatch|WebWhacker|WebXM|WebZip|Weddings.info|wenbin|WEPA|WeRelateBot|Whacker|Widow|WikiaBot|Wikio|wikiwix-bot-|WinHttp.WinHttpRequest|WinHTTP\ Example|WIRE|wired-digital-newsbot|WISEbot|WISENutbot|wish-la|wish-project|wisponbot|WMCAI-robot|wminer|WMSBot|woriobot|worldshop|WorQmada|Wotbox|WPScan|wume_crawler|WWW-Mechanize|www.freeloader.com.|WWW\ Collector|WWWOFFLE|wwwrobot|wwwster|WWWWanderer|wwwxref|Wysigot|X-clawler|Xaldon|Xenu|Xenu's|Xerka\ MetaBot|XGET|xirq|XmarksFetch|XoviBot|xqrobot|Y!J|Y!TunnelPro|yacy.net|yacybot|yarienavoir.net|Yasaklibot|yBot|YebolBot|yellowJacket|yes|YesupBot|Yeti|YioopBot|YisouSpider|yolinkBot|yoogliFetchAgent|yoono|Yoriwa|YottaCars_Bot|you-dir|Z-Add\ Link|zagrebin|Zao|zedzo.digest|zedzo.validate|zermelo|Zeus|Zeus\ Link\ Scout|zibber-v|zimeno|Zing-BottaBot|ZipppBot|zmeu|ZoomSpider|ZuiBot|ZumBot|Zyborg|Zyte).*$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*(Nessus|NESSUS::SOAP|nestReader|Net::Trackback|NetAnts|NetCarta\ CyberPilot\ Pro|Netcraft|NetID.com|NetMechanic|Netprospector|NetResearchServer|NetScoop|NetSeer|NetShift=|NetSongBot|Netsparker|NetSpider|NetSrcherP|NetZip|NetZip-Downloader|NewMedhunt|news|News_Search_App|NewsGatherer|Newsgroupreporter|NewsTroveBot|NextGenSearchBot|nextthing.org|NHSEWalker|nicebot|NICErsPRO|niki-bot|NimbleCrawler|nimbus-1|ninetowns|Ninja|NjuiceBot|NLese|Nogate|Nomad-V2.x|NoteworthyBot|NPbot|NPBot-|NRCan\ intranet|NSDL_Search_Bot|nu_tch-princeton|nuggetize.com|nutch|nutch1|NutchCVS|NutchOrg|NWSpider|Nymesis|nys-crawler|ObjectsSearch|oBot|Obvius\ external\ linkcheck|Occam|Ocelli|Octopus|ODP\ entries|Offline.Explorer|Offline\ Explorer|Offline\ Navigator|OGspider|OmiExplorer_Bot|OmniExplorer_Bot|omnifind|OmniWeb|OnetSzukaj|online\ link\ validator|OOZBOT|Openbot|Openfind|Openfind\ data|OpenHoseBot|OpenIntelligenceData|OpenISearch|OpenSearchServer_Bot|OpiDig|optidiscover|OrangeBot|ORISBot|ornl_crawler_1|ORNL_Mercury|osis-project.jp|OsO|OutfoxBot|OutfoxMelonBot|OWLER-BOT|owsBot|ozelot|P3P\ Client|page_verifier|PageBitesHyperBot|Pagebull|PageDown|PageFetcher|PageGrabber|PagePeeker|PageRank\ Monitor|pamsnbot.htm|Panopy|panscient.com|Pansophica|Papa\ Foto|PaperLiBot|parasite|parsijoo|Pathtraq|Pattern|Patwebbot|pavuk|PaxleFramework|PBBOT|pcBrowser|pd-crawler|PECL::HTTP|penthesila|PeoplePal|perform_crawl|PerMan|PGP-KA|PHPCrawl|PhpDig|PicoSearch|pipBot|pipeLiner|Pita|pixfinder|PiyushBot|planetwork|PleaseCrawl|Plucker|Plukkie|Plumtree|Pockey|Pockey-GetHTML|PoCoHTTP|pogodak.ba|Pogodak.co.yu|Poirot|polybot|Pompos|Poodle\ predictor|PopScreenBot|PostPost|PrivacyFinder|ProjectWF-java-test-crawler|ProPowerBot|ProWebWalker|PROXY|psbot|psbot-page|PSS-Bot|psycheclone|pub-crawler|pucl|pulseBot\ \(pulse|Pump|purebot|PWeBot|pycurl|Python-urllib|pythonic-crawler|PythonWikipediaBot|q1|QEAVis\ agent|QFKBot|qualidade|Qualidator.com|QuepasaCreep|QueryN.Metasearch|QueryN\ Metasearch|quest.durato|Quintura-Crw|QunarBot|Qweery_robot.txt_CheckBot|QweeryBot|r2iBot|R6_CommentReader|R6_FeedFetcher|R6_VoteReader|RaBot|Radian6|radian6_linkcheck|RAMPyBot|RankurBot|RcStartBot|RealDownload|Reaper|REBI-shoveler|Recorder|RedBot|RedCarpet|ReGet|RepoMonkey|RepoMonkey\ Bait|Riddler|RIIGHTBOT|RiseNetBot|RiverglassScanner|RMA|RoboPal|Robosourcer|robot|robotek|robots|Robozilla|rogerBot|Rome\ Client|Rondello|Rotondo|Roverbot|RPT-HTTPClient|rtgibot|RufusBot|Runnk\ online\ rss\ reader|s~stremor-crawler|S2Bot|SafariBookmarkChecker|SaladSpoon|Sapienti|SBIder|SBL-BOT|SCFCrawler|Scich|ScientificCommons.org|ScollSpider|ScooperBot|Scooter|ScoutJet|ScrapeBox|Scrapy|SCrawlTest|Scrubby|scSpider|Scumbot|SeaMonkey$|Search-Channel|Search-Engine-Studio|search.KumKie.com|search.msn.com|search.updated.com|search.usgs.gov|Search\ Publisher|Searcharoo.NET|SearchBlox|searchbot|searchengine|searchhippo.com|SearchIt-Bot|searchmarking|searchmarks|searchmee_v|SearchmetricsBot|searchmining|SearchnowBot_v1|searchpreview|SearchSpider.com|SearQuBot|Seekbot|Seeker.lookseek.com|SeeqBot|seeqpod-vertical-crawler|Selflinkchecker|Semager|semanticdiscovery|Semantifire1|semisearch|SemrushBot|Senrigan|SEOENGWorldBot|SeznamBot|ShablastBot|ShadowWebAnalyzer|Shareaza|Shelob|sherlock|ShopWiki|ShowLinks|ShowyouBot|siclab|silk|Siphon|SiteArchive|SiteCheck-sitecrawl|sitecheck.internetseer.com|SiteFinder|SiteGuardBot|SiteOrbiter|SiteSnagger|SiteSucker|SiteSweeper|SiteXpert|SkimBot|SkimWordsBot|SkreemRBot|skygrid|Skywalker|Sleipnir|slow-crawler|SlySearch|smart-crawler|SmartDownload|Smarte|smartwit.com|Snake|Snapbot|SnapPreviewBot|Snappy|snookit|Snooper|Snoopy|SocialSearcher|SocSciBot|SOFT411\ Directory|sogou|sohu-search|sohu\ agent|Sokitomi|Solbot|sootle|Sosospider|Space\ Bison|Space\ Fung|SpaceBison|SpankBot|spanner|Spatineo\ Monitor\ Controller|special_archiver|SpeedySpider|Sphider|Sphider2|spider|Spider.TerraNautic.net|SpiderEngine|SpiderKU|SpiderMan|Spinn3r|Spinne|sportcrew-Bot|spyder3.microsys.com|sqlmap|Squid-Prefetch|SquidClamAV_Redirector|Sqworm|SrevBot|sslbot|SSM\ Agent|StackRambler|StarDownloader|statbot|statcrawler|statedept-crawler|Steeler|STEGMANN-Bot|stero|Stripper|Stumbler|suchclip|sucker|SumeetBot|SumitBot|SummizeBot|SummizeFeedReader|SuperBot|superbot.com|SuperHTTP|SuperLumin|SuperPagesBot|Supybot|SURF|Surfbot|SurfControl|SurveyBot|suzuran|SWEBot|swish-e|SygolBot|SynapticWalker|Syntryx\ ANT\ Scout\ Chassis\ Pheromone|SystemSearch-robot|Szukacz).*$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
</rule>
```

Regards,
Jalpa

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method might be to add SEMrush to your robots.txt file.  If you need more info about how this works, check Wikipedia for "Robots exclusion standard".

Per the SEMrush site (https://www.semrush.com/bot/), to block SEMrushBot from crawling your site for web graph of links, add the following lines to your robots.txt:

```
User-agent: SemrushBot
Disallow: /
```

Hope this helps.